# Apache 2, SSL, and Client Certificates

Tags: apache2, authentication, mod-ssl

I have set up a number of Virtual Hosts all using SSL. Everything worked fine. Then I needed to add SSL Client Authentication to one of them (let's call it the SVN host). After enabling client certificates for the SVN host, the host stopped working, instead the default virtual host would be used instead (which means that an un-matching server certificate would be provided, so that neither access to the secure host, nor client authentication would work).

Here's the virtual host configuration I'm using:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName  svn.anydomain.com

SSLEngine on
SSLOptions +StrictRequire
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:!SSLv3:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

SSLCertificateFile /etc/certs/svn.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/certs/svn.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/certs/starcom/sub.class1.server.ca.pem
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/certs/cacert.crt
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown

SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 2
SSLUserName SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN

<Location /path0>
    DAV svn
    SSLRequireSSL
    SVNPath /var/svn/path0
    #Require valid-user
</Location>

<Location /path1>
    DAV svn
    SSLRequireSSL
    SVNPath /var/svn/path1
    #Require valid-user
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Also, I seem to have this problem on Mac OS X only. I am able to access the host from Windows 8 with no sweat. Basically, on my Mac I can get it to work only with these options in curl (sometimes, not consistently)

```
curl -v -v -v -1 -k --cacert Documents/Certs/CACert.pem --cert Documents/Certs/ClientCert.pem  https://svn.anydomain.com/path1
```

This instead fails (note the -3 instead of -1 for SSLv3 instead of TLSv1)

```
curl -v -v -v -3 -k --cacert Documents/Certs/CACert.pem --cert Documents/Certs/ClientCert.pem  https://svn.anydomain.com/path1
```

and returns the certificate of the default virtual host. This behaviour (wrong virtual host) is what I get for any access to that domain on my Mac (Safari, Eclipse+Subversive, Cornerstone, etc).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In your apache config file make sure you've added:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
```

See http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI

Make sure that `NameVirtualHost` goes before any `<VirtualHost ...>` that uses that ip and port. If you forget/misplace the `NameVirtualHost` line or the browser does not support SNI, Apache will choose the first available vHost.

Comment: Thanks. My configuration is set up as you described. The interesting thing is that if I remove the "SSLVerifyClient require" directive, everything works. It is literally only that directive that makes my config fail :-(

Comment: It sounds like the issue has something to do with your client itself, not the Apache config. Safari and Cornerstone both use the OSX Keychain, make sure you have your client certificate and chain available in the keychain manager (double check that the client certificate itself has the private key). Eclipse+Subversive need to be manually set up, instructions are at the bottom: http://svn.cacert.org/CAcert/Sysadm/client-certificate-guide.rst

Answer (score 1):

Have you turned up the log level in httpd.conf?  Try running with debug messages enabled and tail -f the error_log to see if anything interesting shows up.

A common problem with SSL client authentication is the SSLVerifyDepth parameter.  The SSLVerifyDepth number needs to be at least as big as the number of certificates in the client certificate's chain.
Example:    SSLVerifyDepth 10

> The depth actually is the maximum number of intermediate certificate issuers, i.e. the number of CA certificates which are max allowed to be followed while verifying the client certificate. A depth of 0 means that self-signed client certificates are accepted only, the default depth of 1 means the client certificate can be self-signed or has to be signed by a CA which is directly known to the server (i.e. the CA's certificate is under SSLCACertificatePath), etc.
>   
> http://www.modssl.org/docs/2.6/ssl_reference.html